# Getting select info from SQLiteDB?

Tags: java, android

I have an SQLiteDB, in one of the tables, I have a column for date (formatted as 3-1-2011) and a column for quantity. I want to grab the quantity for all results in the specified month. So if my table is looking like this:

```
1-28-2011 9
2-2-2011 2
2-5-2011 6
2-12-2011 3
2-20-2011 6
3-1-2011 12
```

How might I go about grabbing just the values from the rows in February and adding them up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention what datatype is used to store the date. I am guessing a string.

If that is the case, you can use **LIKE**.

Modifying skyman's query:

```
SELECT SUM(quantity)
FROM my_table
WHERE date LIKE '2-%'
```

Of course, if you might have rows like **02-xx-xxxx**, then  you would need to account for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your date storing format is not very flexible...
If You would change it to YYYYMMDD query would look like this:

```
SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM my_table WHERE date BETWEEN 2011$(MM)01 AND 2011$(MM)31
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL statement to find the sum of all dates in February:

```
SELECT SUM(MyQuantity)
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  strftime('%m', OrderDate) = '02'
```

Comment: As I know strftime is not able to parse date in non-ISO format. http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: @skyman; right... I didn't catch the fact that the datatype wasn't a proper datetime.